# How to get other user firebase id in realtime database based on his mail or some other id?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm writing an android application with some objects (transactions, categories, etc) grouped together in a project that can be shared among users **on invitation**. E.g. User A creates a project - and only he has access to it **until he shares it with user B** - then they both should have access to that project. I'm using firebase realtime database project to achieve that.
Here is a part of db structure:

```
"transactions": {
  "project1": {
    "SDGSG%$4gs" : {
      "transacationMonth": 7,
      "transactionAmount": 400.67,
      ...
    }
  },
  "project2": {
    ...
  }
},
"categories": {
  "project1": {
    "grtge5g4e5ge45g": {
      "categoryName" : "cat1",
      ...
    }
  },
  "project2" : {
    ...
  }
}
```

and in that structure I have a node "access" that decides which user can access which project:

```
"access": {
  "project1": {
    "uid1": true
  },
  "project2": {
    "uid7": true
  }
}
```

Now, let's say that my application user (with firebase user id = uid1) wants to share his project ("project1") with other firebase user (with firebase user id = uid2). 
From structure perspective it is enough to have the app add the following entry:

```
"access": {
  "project1": {
    "uid1": true,
    "uid2": true,
  },
...
```

But from my android app code perspective I do not know the uid2. I may know for example the mail that user with uid2 is using, but I don't know how to get to uid2 based only on email (or some other attribute like username or whatever).

So... how do I do that?

Comment: During registration store user's ID in database as well.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get unique user id with below code :

```
FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if (user != null) {
        Log.d(TAG,user.getUid());
    }
```

> For every project you have in your database there must be `unique-projectID` and within that
>   store userID that you want to have access to that project.

```
 "access": {
         "unique_projectID": {
         "uid1": true,
         "uid2": true,
         }
     }
```

Let's take an example: Suppose there are two users A and B. Now User A creates a project and project contains only user A's ID .Now user A shares project with user B, therefore B'Id is included in the project.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm doing - the "project1" is a unique project Id. I am getting user ID from getCurrentUser() - but it only gets me "my own" id - so when a user creates a new project - he can do getCurrentUser() to get his own Id and add that. But that doesn't solve the situation when I want the "user2" to be also able to access that project.

Comment: When user A shares project with user B add user B's ID to project ID.

Comment: Since this is not a social media project - he can't and probably shouldn't be able to see what other users are there. He may invite them knowing something about them (like e-mail they used to authenticate themselves in firebase)

Comment: I think You're helping me realize that I will probably have to add some users list with their ids available for everyone to see - to allow user A to add user B's ID to that project.

Comment: No why show other user IDs.Show some other name or email. If you want to do this with email authentication so when authentication is successful then add user B's ID into the project.

Comment: But if won't expose the user ID to be able to be read by other users - I won't be able to enter that ID under "unique_projectID" entry thus allowing him to access the project.

Comment: Store every user's ID during registration in firebase database so it will be easy sharing particular user's ID.